# how to retrieve Python array in javascript (Flask to React communication)

Tags: python, arrays, reactjs, list, flask

I dumped Python array to a response with `json.dumps` and now I'm trying to retrieve the data as Javascript list.

```
@app.route('/get_scales')
@cross_origin()
def get_scales():
    classes = inspect.getmembers(sys.modules['mingus.core.scales'], inspect.isclass)
    scales = [class_[0] for class_ in classes if ('Error' not in class_[0] and class_[0] != '_Scale')]

    return json.dumps(scales)
```

```
  getScales() {
    // create a new XMLHttpRequest
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    // get a callback when the server responds
    xhr.addEventListener("load", () => {
      // update the state of the component with the result here
      console.log(xhr.responseText);
    });
    // open the request with the verb and the url
    xhr.open("GET", "http://127.0.0.1:5000/get_scales");
    // send the request
    xhr.send();

    var formatted_response = JSON.stringify(xhr.responseText);
    console.log(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
    return xhr.responseText;
  }
```

When I made the function in getScales log to console type of xhr.responseText it shows String, but then when trying to parse it with JSON.parse it throws an error. Trying to stringify it first, like above doesn't help either.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what error it gave, but I think it was actually because xhr.response, wasn't there yet when you tried to use it. This is because XMLrequests function asynchronously, meaning that while the XMLrequest is still waiting for a response, the rest of your code continues executing. Try this instead:

```
xhr.open('GET', url, false);
```

the "false" parameter basically says you want your XMLrequest to function synchronously. So the rest of your code will wait for it to finish.

Do keep in mind that your performance may suffer because of this in a lot of situations.
So if you have multiple XMLrequests at a time or Sequentially, you could consider using HTML5 [Workers](https://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html5_webworkers.asp) for this.

Or If you don't want your requests to function synchronously (if you can avoid having your XMLrequest function synchronously, you definitely should) you could also try something like this (something like this is defentintely the best option for performance, so if you can use it):

```
  getScales() {

    // create a new XMLHttpRequest
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    // get a callback when the server responds
    xhr.addEventListener("load", () => {
      // update the state of the component with the result here
      console.log(xhr.responseText);
      var formatted_response = JSON.stringify(xhr.responseText);
      console.log(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
      return xhr.responseText;
    });

    // open the request with the verb and the url
    xhr.open("GET", "http://127.0.0.1:5000/get_scales");

    // send the request
    xhr.send();
  }
```